# Java | Get column keys from a row key

Tags: java, android, hashtable, guava, android-guava

I have Table like     `Table<String, String, String> distributions = HashBasedTable.create();`

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| Row             | Column   | Value           |
|----------------------------------------------|
| aaa             | a        | Hard Rock       |
| aaa             | n        | Art Pop         |
| abc             | b        | Surrealist Film |
| abc             | c        | Blockbuster     |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

My `Column` values are all unique but my `Row` values can be repeated.

so How can I get all the `Column` keys given a `Row` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Table.rowMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#rowMap--) to get "a view that associates each row key with the corresponding map from column keys to values"; the view is a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and its [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) contains all of the `Column` keys for a given `Row` key:

```
 distributions.rowMap().get("aaa").keySet(); // [a, n]
 distributions.rowMap().get("abc").keySet(); // [b, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want values based on **rows**. it will give you multiple values

Comment: Yes I know. and your answer should be a comment